# Select and Count in small SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count, distinct

I have a table with only two columns which is used to assign comments to images.

The first column contains the image ID and the second column the associated comment ID. An image can have multiple comments but each of them has a unique comment ID.

Based on this I would like to get a **ranking in descending order based on the number of comments** per image so the image with the most comments should appear on top.

I tried the following but SQL doesn't accept the combination of Distinct and XML. The idea of using Distinct here was to get rid of duplicates as I only want **each image to appear once in the result**.

How can I achieve this?

My SQL:

```
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT DISTINCT     Top 20 A.imgID,
                COUNT(*) OVER() AS volume,
                (
                    SELECT      B.commentID,
                                COUNT(*) OVER() AS volume
                    FROM        MOC_ImgComments B
                    WHERE       B.imgID = A.imgID
                    FOR XML PATH(''), ELEMENTS, TYPE
                )
    FROM        MOC_ImgComments A
    ORDER BY    volume desc, A.imgID
    FOR XML PATH('images'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('ranks')   

END
```

Comment: You need to add a group by a.imgID to your main query. You also might want to add an order by to your subquery to control the order.

Comment: Thanks ! Regarding the sub query I think I can skip the Order By as I only need the volume there. For the main query, do I just need to group by img ID and that's it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to use GROUP BY clause.  I have not tested the below code.

```
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT    Top 20 A.imgID,
            COUNT(*) OVER() AS volume,
            (
                SELECT      B.commentID,
                            COUNT(*) OVER() AS volume
                FROM        MOC_ImgComments B
                WHERE       B.imgID = A.imgID
                FOR XML PATH(''), ELEMENTS, TYPE
            )
FROM        MOC_ImgComments A
ORDER BY    volume desc, A.imgID
FOR XML PATH('images'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('ranks')   
group by A.imgID
END
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This gives me the correct results (when removing the count from the main query and moving the group by above the xml line but I then cant get it to sort descending by the volume from the sub query.